# Rspec expectations in Cucumber: undefined method 'be' when used inside a class

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara, rspec-expectations

I'm using rspec expectations in a cucumber framework and they look fine when used at the steps definition level.

I've configured my env.rb file with:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
World(RSpec::Matchers)
```

The problem I've noticed now is that if I try to use rspec inside a method of an object that's used inside one of the steps then I've got a failure.

```
E.g.
Steps_definition.rb
   service.use_rspec

class Service
   def use_rspec
       header = page.find("div#services h2").text
       header.should (be 'TV')
   end
 end

Error after execution:
 undefined method `be' for #<Service:0x2592570> (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea where the problem could be?

I've tried a similar assertion with Capybara.page.find(...).should have_content('...') inside that class and 'have_content' is not recognized either, so not really sure what's going on :S

Many thanks for any tip!

Comment: maybe you need World(RSpec::Expectations) ?

Answer (score -1):

Your Service class isn't in the World so RSpec::Matchers isn't available there.

You have two possibilities:

1. Include RSpec::Matchers manually to this class.
2. Put this class (or module) to World. After that its methods will become directly available in step definitions.

Write:

```
class Helpers
  def method
    # Capybara and RSpec::Matchers are available here
  end
end
World{Helpers.new}
```

or

```
module Helpers
  def method
    # Capybara and RSpec::Matchers are available here
  end
 end
World(Helpers)
```

Comment: Hi Andrey.

Not sure where is my problem then. I had put created a module which I put to the World where I had created the service object, so the service methods were available in the steps, that was fine.

The problem I have (even after trying the suggestions above) is that **#Capybara and Rspec::Matchers don't seem to be recognized inside the class.**

If I try:
`include RSpec::Matchers` inside the class then I get the following error `undefined method `new' for RSpec::Matchers::Pretty:Module
Error creating formatter: pretty (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @mickael it works for me. Try to start from scratch. Capybara and RSpec::Matchers are available inside module or class if it's put to  World